# Lambda function returns null from nested async function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

The Lambda function is not hitting the memory limit neither timing out. I read somewhere that it may return because the event loop is empty but I have `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` set to `false`.

Here is the function:

```
module.exports.callMenu = (event, context, callback) => {

  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  const eventJSON = qs.parse(event.body);
  myMongooseObject.findOne({ value: eventJSON.value }, (err, theObject) => {
    if (!err) {

      newObj = new myMongooseObject();
      newObj.message = 'this worked';

      newObj.save((err) => {
        if (!err) {
          callback(null, { body: 'success' });
        } else {
          console.log(err);
        }
      });
    }
};
```

Comment: The functions returns nothing. Do you expect that the callback is called with a specific value? And where do you define "myMongooseObject" and "newCall"?

Comment: I don't understand your question the function should return body:'success'

Comment: Based on the code you provided I would expect the function to fail with "Cannot read property findOne of undefined". myMongooseObject is defined nowhere. And if the .findOne function returns an error it will also run into a timeout. If you add a more solid error handling you may be able to find the issue.

Comment: ok I'm sorry i didn't make it clear that I have that defined and it is returning no errors I figured that would be understood because of what my question was. It doesn't return any errors it just returns null if the callback is inside the save. however it does not return null when outside of the save.

Comment: Does the save return an error? If it does callback is never called and the lambda function returns null by default.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you are not adding callbacks for when there is an error in the request. And you may want to add a try/catch to handle any other issues with your code.

Also, you don't need to set [`callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html) because you are not adding extra events besides your main request.

Try this:

```
const myMongooseObject = defineThisObject(); // maybe you forgot to define it
const qs = defineThisObjectToo(); // maybe another error

module.exports.callMenu = (event, context, callback) => {

    try {
        const eventJSON = qs.parse(event.body);
        myMongooseObject.findOne({ value: eventJSON.value }, (err, theObject) => {

            if (!err) {
                newObj = new myMongooseObject();
                newObj.message = 'this worked';

                // define the newCall object too?

                newCall.save((err) => {
                    if (!err) {
                        callback(null, { body: 'success' });
                    } else {
                        callback(err); // add this
                    }
                });
            } else {
                callback(err); // add this
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
      callback(e);
    }
};
```